# IE11 DOMParser for XML Files "Unspecified Error"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I need to load an XML file into a DOMParser so I can use it more easily client side. The reading of the XML proves no more problem, but when passing the data to the DOMParser it creates an XML document with the text:

**Unspecified Error**

This only happens in IE and Microsoft Edge. FireFox and Chrome both handle it perfectly without any complaining/errors.

Even if I simple give the DOMParser an opening and closing tag with no extra data it throws the error above.

This jsfiddle works in Chrome and FireFox and doesn't in IE and Microsoft Edge. (The jsfiddle throws a different error than my local version does though.)

https://jsfiddle.net/hyfoc6rp/

This is all the jsfiddle does:

```
var data = "<person></person>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
console.log(xmlDoc);
```

Any clues?

Comment: I have this problem also, I tried to just create a xmldocument object from this line var ownerDocument = document.implementation.createDocument("", "test", null); and the result object contains that error in edge.

Comment: I still don't know why the error appears, but I do know that even though the error appears I can still work with it... Sorry I can't be of more help :s

Comment: I can't, I am using two XMLDocument object to create XMLFragment objects, and with the error in both XMLDocument objects as my argument, it is generating null objects. Works fine in chrome and firefox, but not in Edge.